# How lsp-ping works with php in picture?

Tags: ip, mpls, packet-path

If my understanding is correct, lsp-ping will have destination IP addresses set to loopback address(127.0.0.x), to force the label switching of the packet and thus checking the LSP connectivity.

When PHP is happening in LSR before the egress-LSR, the ultimate destination (egress LSR) will receive a plain IP packet with destination set to 127.0.0.x. So how will it treat that packet and end up responding to the lsp-ping?